# Spring State Machine Transitions

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

Im trying to trigger transitions from other ones to make automatic State Machine (SM) but its not working : The initial action (findCustomer() ) is supposed to change the initial state of the SM and then each action triggers an event and so on to the final state. 
Here's my configuration :

```
    @Configuration @EnableStateMachine public class CardStateMachineConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<CardStates, CardEvents> {


    final private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CardStateMachineConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<CardStates, CardEvents> states) throws Exception {
        states.withStates().initial(CardStates.ACTIVE_STATUS).state(CardStates.ACTIVE_STATUS, findCustomer(), null)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(CardStates.class));

    }

    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<CardStates, CardEvents> transitions) throws Exception {




         transitions.withExternal().source(CardStates.ACTIVE_STATUS).target(CardStates.CUSTOMER_FOUND).event(CardEvents.FIND_CUSTOMER).action(findCustomer())
                 .and().withExternal()
         .source(CardStates.CUSTOMER_FOUND).target(CardStates.MOBILECARD_FOUND).event(CardEvents.CUSTOMER_FOUND).action(findMobileCard())
                 .and().withExternal()
         .source(CardStates.FIND_MOBILECARD_FOUND).target(CardStates.WIRECARD_LOCKED_CARD).event(CardEvents.MOBILE_CARD_FOUND).action(wirecardLockCard());


    }

    // @formatter:on
    @Override public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<CardStates, CardEvents> config)
            throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration().autoStartup(true).listener(new MobileCardBlockProcessEventHandler());
    }

    @Bean public Action<CardStates, CardEvents> findCustomer() {

        return (context) -> {
            context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(CardEvents.CUSTOMER_FOUND);
        };

    }

    @Bean public Action<CardStates, CardEvents> findMobileCard() {

        return (context) -> {
            context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(CardEvents.MOBILE_CARD_FOUND);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What went wrong? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1- The SM is instantiated with the initial state CardStates.ACTIVE_STATUS but the findCustomer() action is not triggered. So nothing happens : the SM dont evolve.

2- When i trigger the event CardEvents.FIND_CUSTOMER by using cardStateMachine.sendEvent(CardEvents.FIND_CUSTOMER) from a test class , the findCustomer() action is called + the SM state change but  context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(CardEvents.CUSTOMER_FOUND); is not taken into account : it supposed to call findMobileCard() action as its defined in its transition.

Answer (score 1):

You have event `CardEvents.FIND_CUSTOMER` for `CardStates.ACTIVE_STATUS` to `CardStates.CUSTOMER_FOUND`. From `findCustomer()` you send event `CardEvents.CUSTOMER_FOUND` which is different than `CardEvents.FIND_CUSTOMER`.

Change that and I think it should work. Thought, personally I'd prefer to drive `automatic` machine via anonymous transitions and choice states.

Comment: is there any example of anonymous transitions and choice states in the spring state machine repository or somewhere else?